# How to add us city and state filter in drupal 7 in listing page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have to display city according to state, and according to city have to display records.
How can I do this? I tried by view but was unsuccessful

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I would do something like this:

1. Create a vocabulary 'states'
2. Create a vocabulary 'cities' and add a term reference field that refers 'states'
3. Create a content type that has a term reference fields that refers 'cities'

In views, you could do this:

1. Create a view that shows content of the type you just created in the table format
2. Add the relation between 'states' and 'cities'
3. Now you should be able to add the 'state' and 'city' fields to your table.

Comment: What if I want to add all countries of the world with states and cities as taxonomy? Doing it manually is not an option obviously. There has to be something. Do you know?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module for displaying city according to state selected.

1. First you need to create a taxonomy vocabulary states
2. Add a state (Eg: Texas)
3. Add cities coming under that state and drag to align the weight.
4. Install the above module
5. Add new term reference field with hierarchical select

You can easily list the city according to state by using this module and taxonomy field.